# ElasticSearch get random results with multiple filters doesn't work

Tags: php, elasticsearch, random, documents, nosql

Not getting proper results from elasticsearch with multiple filters.

I am following the documentation: 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/random-scoring.html

It returns results for the very first filter and did not apply others filters like we can add AND operator in SQL statement.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/combining-filters.html